# Polynomial group matching

Tags: regex

I have this regex: `(\+|\-)?[a-z0-9.^]+` that matches all the groups in a polynomial with only positive integers like `2x^2+3x+0`.

Using that regex I get the result `2x^2`, `+3x`, `+0`. Everything ok as far. The problem comes when I have negative exponents like `2x^-2+3x+0`.

Using that regex I get the result `2x^`, `-2`, `+3x`, `+0`.

I need to know how can I take the first `-` after the `^`

Comment: O.o I guess so, Now it works like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include a minus after a power in your regular expression you could remove caret off the character class and use it in an optional non-capturing group:

```
[+-]?(?:[a-z0-9.]+(?:\^-?)?)+
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9GiBW/1)